# Trends metric on Kibana Dashboard, it’s possible?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dashboard, metrics

I want to create a metric in kibana dashboard, which use ratio of multiple metrics and offset period.

Example :

Date            Budget

YYYY-MM-DD        $

2019-01-01      15

2019-01-02      10

2019-01-03      5

2019-01-04      10

2019-01-05      12

2019-01-06      4

If I select time range between 2019-01-04 to 2019-01-06 , I want to compute ratio with offset period: 2019-01-01 to 2019-01-03.

to resume : (sum(10+12+4) - sum(15+10+5)) / sum(10+12+4) = -0.15
evolution of my budget equal to -15% (and this is what I want to print in the dashboard)

But, with metric it's not possible (no offset), with visual builder: different metric aggregation do not have different offset (too bad because bucket script allow to compute ratio), and with vega : I not found a solution too.

Any idea ? Thanks a lot

Aurélien

NB: I use kibana version > 6.X

Comment: hey @Aurelien, I can share you the aggregation query if that's useful, unfortunately I am not sure how do I use that query to construct a `metric visualizer` in `kibana`. Let me know so I can post my query.

Comment: hi @kamal, I am interested to see your aggregation. thanks

Comment: sure, please check the answer. I've posted the aggregation query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the below sample mapping which I've constructed based on data you've provided in the query and aggregation solution that you wanted to take a look.

### Mapping:

```
PUT <your_index_name>
{
  "mappings": {
    "mydocs": {
      "properties": {
        "date": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
        },
        "budget": {
          "type": "float"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Aggregation

I've made use of the following types of aggregation:

- [Date Histogram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) where I've mentioned interval as `4d` based on the data you've mentioned in the question
- [Sum](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html)
- [Derivative](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-derivative-aggregation.html)
- [Bucket Script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html) which actually gives you the required budget evolution figure.

Also I'm assuming that the date format would be in `yyyy-MM-dd` and `budget` would be of `float` data type.

Below is how your aggregation query would be.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "date": {
        "gte": "2019-01-01",
        "lte": "2019-01-06"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "my_date": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "date",
        "interval": "4d",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_budget": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "budget"
          }
        },
        "budget_derivative": {
          "derivative": {
            "buckets_path": "sum_budget"
          }
        },
        "budget_evolution": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "input_1": "sum_budget",
              "input_2": "budget_derivative"
            },
            "script": "(params.input_2/params.input_1)*(100)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the result that you are looking for would be in the `budget_evolution` part.

Hope this helps!

Comment: derivative method in elastic aggregation is a good idea for my purpose. thanks a lot, Aurelien